# Is it possible to access the Cacti RRD database over the network

Tags: c#, rrdtool, rrd, cacti

is it possible to access the Cacti RRD (Round Robin Database) from a different machine over the network?  We want to be able to create our own custom graphs by querying the Cacti RRD database (e.g. given a router hostname, give me the bandwidth usage on all its interfaces for the past 4 hours). So all we really want from Cacti is the raw data points required to build the graphs/plots.  We don't need it to generate the graph images.

The Cacti service is deployed on a linux machine and the queries will be invoked from a Windows .Net application

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i posted in the RRD user's group and immediately got responses on 3 ways of doing this:

1)  rrd server (uses inetd for the connection handling)
http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/doc/rrdtool.en.html

2) rrdcached
http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/doc/rrdcached.en.html

3) JSON output for rrdtool (XPORT mod)
http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/forum.en.html#nabble-td5629054|a5629054

The only tricky part is figuring out which rrd file to load into the RRDTool.

Comment: We ended up just writing a python application that wraps around the RRDs using the rrdpython library (http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdpython.en.html) and works over TCP.